# Are DXO scores of mobiles and cameras directly comparable?

Tags: cameraphones, hasselblad, dxo-optics

The DXO score for the mobile camera (photo) Huawei Mate 30 Pro camera is 121 and for the medium format camera, Hasselblad X1D-50c is 102. Although the parameters are different for mobiles and cameras does it imply the mobile is "better" than the camera at least in some respects?

Answer (score 3):

No. The score for different categories of cameras are independent of one another. They're not only on different scales, but some of the categories for which they are evaluated differ as well.